# Pass Html page as method parameter

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have an WebForms application that sends a customized email.
I created a Body.html file in the solution and i would like to pass this .html file as a parameter to the `SendMail` method. This .html file is the body of the email.

Can I do that? How?

Something like

```
void SendMail(HtmlFile bodyEmail)
{}
```

Thanks!

---

I forgot to mention that the SendMail() method is in a different dll. And i would like to pass the .html class as a .html file, not as a string. Thats the point. Becouse it´s a huge html file.

Something like:

void SendMail(HtmlFile bodyMail)
{}

Any ideas?
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

pass the content of the html file as  text as a String field

```
void SendMail(String bodyEmail) {}
```

or pass the path to the file as String field an read the contents of the file within de SendMail method

Comment: The problem is that the html file is really big to pass in a string. Theres no other way to pass is as a .html class? or something like that.

Comment: then pass the filepath and load it in the sendmail method